# Bootstrap 4: how to set the grid of specific responsive squares - Col or Card?

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

For my index page I need to set such a grid:
[image]

For `Col-md` item 8 should stand under items 4 and 5.
For `Col-sm` the blocks go: `item 1`, lower - `item 4` and `5`, lower - `2` and `3`, lower - `6 and 7`, lower - `item 8`.

All the blocks should be clickable.

Tried some variants using cols and cards. Didn't get any result to show it here.

Any ideas?

UPD: Tried this.

```html
<style>
      div{background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);}
      .square{height: 166 px; width: 166px;}
      .expo_announcements{height: 166px; width: 337px;}
      .big_square{height: 337px; width: 337px;}
</style>

<div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 expo_announcements" style="background-color: red;">
              <p>Item 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 square" style="background-color: #0058a1;">
              <p>Item 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-2 square" style="background-color: #9cbd3c;">
              <p>Item 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 big_square" style="background-color: #f1ecbd;">
              <p>Item 8</p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far

Comment: For desktop: your screenshot... for md: 1-4-5-8-2-3-6-7; for sm: 1-4-5-2-3-6-7-8 - can you confirm ?